# How to get back to function from timed event

Tags: c#, mono, sensors, modbus

Okay so I have a function called readSensor which you guessed it.. reads a sensor.

But the sensors usually take about 100ms to respond. So in the readSensor function I am basically just starting a timer.

On the timed event I read the serialport and get my response.

However this means that my response is in the onTimedEvent when I want it to be in the readSensor function..

Basically from the main form I want to be able to do this.

value = readSensor()

when at the minute all I can do is readSensor() and then I can see the response is coming back by displaying it in a messagebox once the timedEvent fires.

here is my code. (I have missed out loads of serialport setup and stuff but hopefully you can see the problem I am in)

I don't want to just wait in the function for 100ms though polling the timer as that will make my program slow..

I want to somehow get the response back to the readSensor function and then back to the form.

```
    using System;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.IO.Ports;
    using System.Timers;

    namespace readSensor
    {
      public partial class readSens : UserControl
      {
        public readSens()
        {
          InitializeComponent();
        }

        private System.Timers.Timer rTimer;
        SerialPort sp = new SerialPort();

        private void setupTimer()
        {
          // Create a timer with a 100ms response.
          rTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(100);
          rTimer.SynchronizingObject = this;
          // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
          rTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        }

        private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
          string response = getResponse();
        }

        public string getResponse()
        {
          string status = "";
          byte[] readBuffer = new byte[255];
          if (sp.IsOpen)
          {
            if (sp.BytesToRead > 0) //there is data to read
            {
              int length = sp.BytesToRead;

              for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
              {
                readBuffer[i] = (byte)sp.ReadByte();
                status = "pass";
                return status;
              }
            }
         }

        public void readSensor(byte addr)
        {
          if (!sp.IsOpen)
          {
            openPort();
            readSensor(addr); // calls itself again once port is opened
          }
          else if (sp.IsOpen)
          {
            rTimer.Start();
          }
          else
          {
            MessageBox.Show("Port not opened yet");
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

In the main form I am basically just saying

```
setupTimer();
readSensor();
```

on a button click.

Comment: Have you tried something like: while(time not over) yield(); I'm guessing your readSensor(); is multithreaded?

Comment: Sorry could you explain a little more what you mean here? I have never used "yield" before..

Comment: Sorry i was thinking in C for a moment, yield in C# is something different, in C yield (not a standard function) starts the scheduler (the think which say what program may run now) so it stops your process, does other stuff and then returns, if the time has passed you proceed if not you yield again, its like stretching your method over the time but not blocking other processes

Comment: If you have multiple Threads for readSensor, can't you use Thread.Sleep(100); ? (It's in Threading i think, Thread.Sleep waits the given time in ms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start a separate thread, then from that thread write into a queue the results back in your main thread.

```
class Game1
{
    //We declare a queue, which is like an array that we can extract and enter data easily in a FIFO (first in, first out) style list.
    Queue<string> q = new Queue<string>();

    public void threadStart(object obj)
    {
        //We get the result of your function, while our main function is still looping and waiting.
        string result = readInput()
        //We tell C# that the parameter we passed in, is in fact the Game1 class passed from "t.Start"
        Game1 game = (Game1)obj;
        //This puts our "result" into the queue.
        game.q.Enqueue(result);
    }

    public void start()
    {
        //Declares a new thread, which will run "threadStart" function.
        System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(threadStart);

        //We start the other thread (that will run in parallel) and pass "this" as the parameter.
        t.Start(this);

        //We loop over and over, sleeping, whilst the other function runs at the same time. This is called "multi- threading"
        while (q.Count == 0)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
        }

        //This gets the last-entered (oldest) value from the queue q.
        string result = q.Deque();
    }
}
```

So this sets off a thread to get the result, and then in my version, polls the queue for a while until the results come back, but in yours could do a bunch of stuff, as long as you check the queue every now and again for new data.

Edit: Added commenting to hopefully alleviate some of your questions.

Comment: I want to say thanks, but I don't understand much of this..

Just when I thought I was getting c#.. I guess I will have to read up on queuing.. also I keep seeing <string> popping up.. is this not the same as casting like (string) ?

Comment: <string> is generics not casting, meaning that queue is a queue of strings

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do it without some callback mechanism. You could implement a while loop but that is not eficient as it would introduce spinning.

My advice is to implement a proper async pattern or something simple like:

```
ReadSensor(addr, DoSomethingWithResult);

public void DoSomethingWithResult(string result)
{
    Console.WriteLine (result);
}

public partial class ReadSens : UserControl
{
    private Action<string> _responseCallback;

    public void ReadSensor(byte addr, Action<string> responseCallback)
    {   
        _responseCallback = responseCallback;

        // initiate timer
    }

    private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        string response = getResponse();

        _responseCallback(response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh this looks promising.. I understand callbacks from my dabbling in Node.js, I will have to read up on how they work in C#..

I see that read sensor has a callback function, I dont really get the whole  _responseCallback = responseCallback; bit though..

Comment: What you do is you create a method, in this example, DoSomethingWithResult, you pass it to the ReadSensor and store it on a variable. Then as soon as the OnTimeEvent has a response, it will call the callback function and you can do whatever you need.

Comment: This is great. I am going to try and implement it.. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Could be this approach a valid solution for you? I think you only are using `Timer` to wait the serialPort to be open, but it can be self-controlled with raising event.

```
public class SensorReader
{
    private Sensor sensor;
    private string lastResponse;

    public SensorReader(SerialPort serialPort)
    {
        this.serialPort = aSerialPort.
        this.sensor = new Sensor(serialPort);
        this.sensor.PortOpen += PortOpenEventHandler(OnPortOpen);
    }

    private void OnPortOpen()
    {
        this.ReadPort();
    }

    public string ReadPort(byte address)
    {
        if (!this.sensor.IsOpen)
        {
            this.sensor.OpenPort();
            this.lastResponse = "The serial port doesn't respond... yet!";
        }
        else
        {
            // Read response at this point.
            this.lastResponse = this.GetResponse();
        }           

        return this.lastResponse;
    }
}

public class Sensor
{
    private SerialPort serialPort;

    public Sensor(SerialPort aSerialPort)
    {
        this.serialPort = aSerialPort;
    }

    public bool IsOpen
    {
        get { return this.serialPort.IsOpen; }
    }

    public delegate void PortOpenEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

    public event PortOpenEventHandler PortOpen;

    public void OpenPort()
    {
        // Open port here...

        // ... and throw the PortOpen event.
        if (this.PortOpen != null)
        {
            this.PortOpen(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help but I am actually using the timer to wait for the response.. the sensors I have process my request and usually respond within 100ms so that's why I am waiting 100ms for the response.. anything over and I am considering it a timeout